# Shortening if-statements of displaying errors

Tags: php, validation

Is it possible to shorten this piece of PHP code?

Honestly, I think it does not look clean but like a mess.

```
if(Input::exists() && $token) {
    if($validation->error('firstname') && $validation->error('lastname')) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not enter your name.</div>', "\n";
    } else if($validation->error('firstname')) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not enter your first name</div>', "\n";
    } else if($validation->error('lastname')) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not enter your last name.</div>', "\n";
    }
}
if(!Input::exists()) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition">↳ We will address you by this name.</div>', "\n";
}

if(Input::exists() && $token) {
    if($validation->error('emailConfirm') == 'match') {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ The email address you entered does not match.</div>', "\n";
    } else if($validation->error('emailConfirm') == 'type') {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not re-enter a valid email address.</div>', "\n";
    } else if($validation->error('emailConfirm')) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not re-enter your email to confirm.</div>', "\n";
    }
}else if(!Input::exists()) {
        echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition">↳ Re-enter your email to make sure it\'s correct.</div>', "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are repeating the same code:

```
echo str_repeat(' ', 20), '<div class="addition error">↳ You did not enter your name.</div>', "\n";
```

Replace it with a function which will do the job:

```
function message($content, $class = ''){
    return str_repeat(' ', 20) . '<div' . (($class) ? " class='$class'" : '') . ">$content</div>\n";
}
```

You are using construction:

```
if () {} else if() {}
```

This is the same as:

```
if () {} else { if() {} }
```

I guess, that it is not what you want to use, the correct construction should be:

```
if () {} elseif() {}
```

The code itself can be rewritten like this:

```
function message($content, $class = ''){
    return str_repeat(' ', 20) . '<div' . (($class) ? " class='$class'" : '') . ">$content</div>\n";
}

if (!Input::exists()){
    echo message('We will address you by this name.', 'addition');
    echo message('Re-enter your email to make sure it\'s correct.', 'addition');
} elseif (Input::exists() && $token) {
    if($validation->error('firstname') && $validation->error('lastname')) {
        echo message('You did not enter your name.', 'addition error');
    } elseif($validation->error('firstname')) {
        echo message('You did not enter your first name', 'addition error');
    } else {
        echo message('You did not enter your last name.', 'addition error');
    }

    if($validation->error('emailConfirm') == 'match') {
        echo message('The email address you entered does not match.', 'addition error');
    } elseif($validation->error('emailConfirm') == 'type') {
        echo message('You did not re-enter a valid email address.', 'addition error');
    } else {
        echo message('You did not re-enter your email to confirm', 'addition error');
    }
}
```